# Variables set in .env is not present inside the docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have added a few variables in a `.env` file.

e.g.

```
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
```

[Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) does not create a user with those credentials.

I can not see them when I run `docker exec -it $(docker ps | ack postgre | cut -f1 -d\ ) env` either.

Why isn't the environnment variables I set in .env honored when I start docker-compose?

Comment: Check if the variables are accessible in your container with `docker-compose config`. Do you see your variables?

Comment: Nope! :-(  I'm using docker-compose version 1.11.2

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that one has to tell docker-compose that an .env file exists:

e.g.

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-envfile-configuration-option